# React app that generates PDF files is not always loading images

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a React app that I am using to generate PDF files. I am currently trying to have images in the PDF files and I am use the <img> tag for this. The issues I am running into is that sometimes the images load in the PDF file and sometimes they do not. The images are injected in a JSX file that is a component of the PDF file.

The source of the images is a link to a photo in [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) and I have not tried other image hosting options. I also have tried uploading the image to the public images folder and have not had success with the images loading.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.